# How to apply a binary function to a cell array and a double array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of arrays (e.g. character vectors) that takes positional indexing and a double array containing positing integers that are meant to be array indices. Is there a native function that can apply the indices to the cell of arrays?

For example,

```
A={'abc','asdfc','aojcdfw','casd'};
B=[3,5,4,1];
```

Is there a native function that can output the following?

```
{A{1}(B(1):end), A{2}(B(2):end), A{3}(B(3):end), A{4}(B(4):end)}
```

Comment: Why not just write a loop? It's not going to be any slower than any of the solutions below.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I didn't know of `extractAfter`. I had `cellfun` in mind and only think of it as a matter of convenience over looping. Next time, I'll be sure to test whether loop is not any slower. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`extractAfter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractafter.html) does exactly this.

```
>> extractAfter(A, B-1)
ans =
  1×4 cell array
    {'c'}    {'c'}    {'cdfw'}    {'casd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). For `cellfun`, all inputs must be cells, so I first convert `B` to cell using `num2cell`.

```
cellfun(@(a,b) a(b:end), A, num2cell(B), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know of any other way by any chance? I don't have any efficiency concern for this application. But ordinarily, cell arrays cost more memory overhead right?